# Why Python can't unzip properly a ZIP file through a shell script on Mac OS X?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, macos, shell, unzip

**ENVRIONMENT:**

Mac OS X Catalina 10.15

Python 3.10

I worked since days on this task. I am developping a software for Mac OS with Python. I use Py2App to convert my python software in MySoftware.app

My software will need to autoupdate itself when it detect a new version.

So my idea was to auto download the new app "MySoftware.app", remove the old app folder "/Applications/MySoftware.app", and then copy paste the new one in the folder "/applications".

I tried it all!!!!

I used:

- packages to make a pkg
- dmg to mount image and extract to /Applications
- zip file and unzip to /Applications

All these technics run fine by hand but it bugs when I automate it through a python script. I constantly get the error "You can't open the application "MySoftware" because it may be damaged or incomplete." when I double click on my app.

So I made a bash script which :

- download a zip file which contains the new "MySoftware.app"
- unzip it
- remove old "/Applications/MySoftware.app"
- cp -R new one to "/Applications"

**Shell Script AutoUpload.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "------------- STARTING AutoUpdate.sh -----------------"
# If MySoftware.app doesn't exist, we unzip MySoftware_MAC.zip
if [[ ! -d "MySoftware.app" ]];then
  echo "The directory MySoftware.app doesn't exist"
  if [[ -f "MySoftware_MAC.zip" ]];then
    unzip MySoftware_MAC.zip
    echo "The file MySoftware_MAC.zip has been unzipped"
  else
    curl -sSL https://www.MySoftware.co/dist/MySoftware_MAC.zip --output MySoftware_MAC.zip
    unzip MySoftware_MAC.zip
    echo "The file MySoftware_MAC.zip has been unzipped"
  fi
fi
rm -rf /Applications/MySoftware.app
echo "The folder /Applications/MySoftware.app has been removed"
#curl -sSL https://www.MySoftware.co/dist/MySoftware_MAC.zip --output MySoftware_MAC.zip
#echo "The file MySoftware_MAC.zip has been downloaded"
#unzip MySoftware_MAC.zip

cp -R MySoftware.app /Applications
echo "The folder MySoftware.app has been copied pasted to the folder /Applications"
osascript -e 'quit app "MySoftware"'
echo "The application MySoftware has been Quit"
open /Applications/MySoftware.app/Contents/MacOS/MySoftware
echo "The new application /Applications/MySoftware has been open"
```

It works perfectly fine when I execute this shell script from terminal. I can even run  the new MySoftware.app

But it bugs when I run it from my python script.

**Python Script:**

```
down_url = f"http://www.MySoftware.co/dist/MySoftware_MAC.zip"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(down_url, MySoftware_MAC.zip)
down_url = f"http://www.MySoftware.co/dist/AutoUpdate.sh"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(down_url, 'AutoUpdate.sh')
os.system(f"chmod 755 'AutoUpdate.sh'")
command_run_autopupdate_shell_sript = f"""/usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script "/bin/bash 'AutoUpdate.sh' >> {os.environ['HOME']}/log_AutoUpdate.log" with prompt "Software need to install some programs." with administrator privileges'"""

proc = subprocess.Popen(command_run_autopupdate_shell_sript, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
(output, err) = proc.communicate()
logger.info(output.decode("utf8"))
logger.info(err.decode("utf8"))
returncode_command_install_Software = proc.wait()
logger.info(f"returncode_command_install_software : {returncode_command_install_Software}")
```

So I tried to execute it as "root", but still the same issue. The script unzip "MySoftware.app" badly. And the worst of all, it doesn't show any error message. The code return is 0.

```
returncode_command_install_software : 0
```

As you can see in screenshot below, I get the MySoftware.app with a wrong icon. When I double click on it, I get this popup error message:

"You can't open the application "MySoftware" because it may be damaged or incomplete."

[image]

To simulate this autoupdate, I execute my python script after I compiled it with Py2App.

Do you guys have any idea w

Comment: Why are you telling Python to start a shell to start osascript to start another shell (that itself starts _yet another_ shell)? Why not just tell python to start osascript directly?

Comment: My python code is downloading the ZIP file (which contains MySoftware.app) and the shell script "AutoUpdate.sh" ; and then it executes the shell script as Admin with oascript. Then this AutoUpdate.sh script is trying to unzip the zip file.